# Google App engine Dagger Bootstrap injection for Dependency Injection

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dependency-injection, google-cloud-endpoints, dagger

I am creating an app on the Google App Engine platform using Cloud endpoints. I read that Dagger is the recommended way for DI in google app engine but it requires Bootstrap Injection to build its object graph that can be used for injections in fashion similar to:

```
class CoffeeApp implements Runnable {
  @Inject CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker;

  @Override public void run() {
    coffeeMaker.brew();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new DripCoffeeModule());
    CoffeeApp coffeeApp = objectGraph.get(CoffeeApp.class);
    ...
  }
}
```

This is because

> In order to put the graph to use we need to bootstrap injection. This
>   usually requires injecting the main class of a command line app, or
>   the activity classes of an Android app. In our coffee example, the
>   CoffeeApp class is used to start dependency injection. (As mentioned on the dagger website)

I understand that I would need to create the graph in the a `ServletContextListener` but I do not get the part where I inject the "Main class" of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the graph before attempting to use it to inject any objects.  You don't necessarily have to do it in your `ServletContextListener`, although that's a reasonable candidate.

Once the graph is initialized, you can use it to self-inject your Cloud Endpoints (through field injection).

Comment: Hey Andy, can you please elaborate? What do you mean by "you can use it to self-inject your Cloud Endpoints (through field injection)"?

Comment: Well, that depends on which version of Dagger you're using.  Since it's 2016 now, I'm going to guess you're using Dagger 2.  In that case, in the constructor of your endpoint class (e.g. `MyEndpoint`) you would get your Dagger component from your ServletContextListener, and, assuming it implements an interface with a method like `void inject(MyEndpoint endpoint)`, then you would just call `myComponent.inject(this)`.